# Gravitational recoil with stars/planets...?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, gravitational-waves

When two black holes are merging, one of them can be ejected if it has less mass than the other black hole, so the gravitational waves emitted by both of them is unbalanced, and the more strong ones would "kick" the smaller black hole out of the merger, sometimes even kicking it out of the galaxy. This is known as gravitational recoil.

Can this also happen with other objects like stars or planets so that they can get ejected to very high speeds? If not by the same mechanism, maybe through a similar one?

Comment: do you have a reference/link  for this statement?

Comment: Gravitational recoil involves the ejection of the _merged_ black hole _after_ the merger.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters already mentioned, *gravitational recoil* during black hole merger refers to velocity gained (relative to the center of mass frame of the merging pair)  by resultant big black hole.

But yes, there are variety of mechanisms through which stars can gain enough velocity to get ejected from their galaxy (such stars are called *hypervelocity stars*). The most notable is the Hills mechanism, a 3-body exchange when a stellar binary passes near a massive black hole (MBH, e.g. at the center of a galaxy). As a result one component of the binary becomes bound to a black hole while the other gets ejected, possibly with enough velocity to leave the galaxy. The mechanism is illustrated by the following image (taken from [Brown 2015](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev-astro-082214-122230)):

[image: Hills mechanism]

A variation of this mechanism is 3-body exchange with two MBH and a star, initially orbiting one of the black holes, see [Guillochon & Loeb 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5022). As a result, MBHs merge and a star gets ejected, possibly with velocity exceeding those achievable by black hole merger recoil, up to $\sim 10^5 \text{ km}\cdot \text{s}^{-1}$. Since galactic MBHs normally have many stars in close orbits around them, a merger of two galactic MBHs could be accompanied by ejection of multiple hypervelocity stars (see image).

[image: Ejection mechanism from Guillochon & Loeb]

Comment: and could there be a merging event between two MBH where one of the MBH gets ejected by the gravitational recoil effect while the stars orbiting any of the MBH would also be ejected? @A.V.S.

Comment: @vengaq If one of BHs is ejected, then there is no merger, is there? And the net effect of stars on the motion of MBHs is a dissipative force, [dynamical friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_friction), so once MBHs are orbiting each other, they would merge. But the resultant big BH *can* be ejected from the galaxy (though I do not think it is likely).